# "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch" z-index bug on Chrome for Mac OSX

Tags: css, webkit

I've recently been having some issues with some tooltips on a webpage not displaying properly on the Mac OSX version of Chrome (and occasionally on some Windows versions, though that isn't a consistent thing).  I've isolated the problem as being the property "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch," set on an HTML tag (from Normalize).

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to squash this bug without having to necessarily remove the -webkit-overflow-scrolling tag.  I guess it is kind of silly to try and preserve behavior for touch and hover, so maybe some sort of media query on that particular property would solve the problem?

Here's a fiddle showcasing the behavior:  http://jsfiddle.net/N4cJX/6/

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed on the newest Chrome builds, see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124559.